# how to get first key (0 or associative ) form array and output in new array

Tags: php, arrays

I Would Like To Get The First Element Of This Array And Put In New Same Array Output

One Requirement: It Cannot Be Done With Passing By reference Index eg 0

This Input Array

```
        [ 'id','ID','dt-text' ] ,
        [ 'name','Name','dt-text' ] ,
        [ 'artistList'=>['list','mm','defalut']  ,'Artist List','dt-select'] ,
        [ 'nationality'=>['nationality','mm','defalut']  ,'Nationality','dt-select'] ,
        [ 'view','View',''],
        [ 'status','Status' ,'']

array:6 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
        0 => "id"
        1 => "ID"
        2 => "dt-text"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
        0 => "name"
        1 => "Name"
        2 => "dt-text"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
        "artistList" => array:3 [▼
              0 => "list"
              1 => "mm"
              2 => "defalut"
        ]
        0 => "Artist List"
        1 => "dt-select"
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
        "nationality" => array:3 [▼
              0 => "nationality"
              1 => "mm"
              2 => "defalut"
        ]
        0 => "Nationality"
        1 => "dt-select"
  ]
  4 => array:3 [▼
        0 => "view"
        1 => "View"
        2 => ""
  ]
  5 => array:3 [▼
        0 => "status"
        1 => "Status"
        2 => ""
  ]
]
```

The New Array  I Needed

This IS OutPUT Array

```
['id','name','artistList'=>['list','mm','defalut'] ,'nationality'=>['nationality','mm','defalut'] ,'view','status']
array:6 [▼
    0 => "id"
    1 => "name"
    "artistList" => array:3 [▼
                0 => "list"
                1 => "mm"
                2 => "defalut"
                ]
    "nationality" => array:3 [▼
                0 => "nationality"
                1 => "mm"
                2 => "defalut"
                ]
    2 => "view"
    3 => "status"
]
```

Note 
I Can Controll in Input Array Same , I Try with foreach in php  And Tray In Laravel  Helper Function head Put I get S

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "artistList" => array:3 [▼
      0 => "list"
      1 => "mm"
      2 => "defalut"
    ]
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    "nationality" => array:3 [▼
      0 => "nationality"
      1 => "mm"
      2 => "defalut"
    ]
  ]
  4 => "view"
  5 => "status"
]
```

Put I Cant Get Resslut So , How Can I Do this?

Comment: I don't completely understand your requirement. Do you want a new array as output, or overwrite the old array. Why can't you pass by reference? Can you use reference in the `foreach`?

Comment: yes i want array same output 
['id','name','artistList'=>['list','mm','defalut'] ,'nationality'=>['nationality','mm','defalut'] ,'view','status']

"reference" i mean in some array number 0 is associative

i hope you understand me i am soory for bad english

Comment: Your shift button is being excessively used. It becomes hard to read

Comment: @Andreas I Am Edit Text

Comment: @Nick I need reslut same as 

['id','name','artistList'=>['list','mm','defalut'] ,'nationality'=>['nationality','mm','defalut'] ,'view','status']

array:6 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  "artistList" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "list"
    1 => "mm"
    2 => "defalut"
  ]
  "nationality" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "nationality"
    1 => "mm"
    2 => "defalut"
  ]
  2 => "view"
  3 => "status"
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are changing the keys (structure) of the array, there is no way to do that without either generating a new array or passing the array by reference. One way to do it by generating a new array is with [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$array = [
        [ 'id','ID','dt-text' ] ,
        [ 'name','Name','dt-text' ] ,
        [ 'artistList'=>['list','mm','defalut']  ,'Artist List','dt-select'] ,
        [ 'nationality'=>['nationality','mm','defalut']  ,'Nationality','dt-select'] ,
        [ 'view','View',''],
        [ 'status','Status' ,'']
    ];
$array = array_reduce($array, function ($c, $v) { 
    $first_key = array_keys($v)[0];
    return array_merge($c, array($first_key => $v[$first_key])); }, []);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [0] => id
  [1] => name
  [artistList] => Array (
    [0] => list
    [1] => mm
    [2] => defalut
  )
  [nationality] => Array (
    [0] => nationality
    [1] => mm
    [2] => defalut
  )
  [2] => view
  [3] => status
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/sUiRX)